# How to describe web application design experience

Tags: resume

How should I elaborate about my experience in web application design on my resume? I'm having a hard time deciding what would be adequate.

Are we talking about UI, classes, specific components?

**Edit #1**

More precisely, I need to indicate experience in design, modeling and programming. The last two I was able to cover.

Comment: @gnat - I think this is a little different, based on the edit than just a list of skills.

Comment: @JeffO http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Answer (score 2):

Just describe what you did. Any specifics that the interviewer will want to know will be asked during the interview. List the technologies you've worked with, as well.

What they want to see is what you accomplished, and the more math, the better. For example: "using xx technology, I developed xx that reduced compilation time by 50%." That is much more useful than "I implemented xx".

Comment: How about in the context of having to describe your experience in terms of design, modelling and programming. At this point, only missing design.

Comment: Again, they will ask that in the interview. Or better yet, if they don't, bring it up when they ask about the project. Recruiters don't like reading long resume's. Their only purpose is to get you the interview.

Answer (score 1):

Describe the project(s) you've worked on and indicate your role in the design and modeling. Mention if you used any known strategies, methodology and best practices. Many websites have different components: graphics, UI, server, database, tiers, layers, so list the parts you worked on that are relevant to each job application. The amount of traffic the site could handle would be an indication of your design ability as well.

Those interviewing you will know the difference between designing a page in html and a full web application.